# How to perform groupby with shift with rolling window similar to pandas in pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

How can I apply this code snippet of pandas in PySpark dataframe?

```
df.groupby(["day","Article"])['QTY'].transform(
                             lambda x: x.shift(1).rolling(window=10).mean())
```

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas.html

Comment: @Chris isn't there any pyspark.sql function for this? As calling native python has its own cost.

Comment: You can use window in pyspark to replicate this

Comment: you usually get better answers if you provide sample input data and expected output